# LibGdx Multiple touch - Handling Listeners

Tags: java, android, libgdx, multi-touch

I´ve  got some issues involving multiple touches.

There is a Stage (mainStage) with an Actor(playLight, code below) on it, a HUD Stage(HUD.stage) and a InputMultiplexer to process both stages.

```
inputMultiplexer= new InputMultiplexer();
    inputMultiplexer.addProcessor(HUD.stage);
    inputMultiplexer.addProcessor(mainStage);
```

I want to handle input by two finger so the one finger can move my object and the other can swipe up and down or double tap anywhere on my stage, except for  on the spot my Actor is on

I am using a Listener for both my Main Stage:...

```
mainStage.addListener(new ActorGestureListener(5,0.3f,0.4f,2f){
        @Override
        public void pan(InputEvent event, float x, float y, float deltaX, float deltaY) {
            if(event.getPointer() == LightHandler.playerLight.pointerUsed){
                listeningToPointer = -1;
                return;
            }

            listeningToPointer= event.getPointer();
            if(deltaY>0){
                mainCharacter.up();
            }
            else{
                mainCharacter.down();
            }
        }


        @Override
        public void tap(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int count, int button) {

            if(count==2){
                mainCharacter.clicked();
                }
        }
    });
```

..and for an object on this (mainStage) stage

```
playerLight.addListener(new DragListener(){
        @Override
        public void drag(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer) {
            pointerUsed = pointer;  // will be reset to -1 at the end of update()
            setPosition(getX()+ Gdx.input.getX(pointerUsed)-getWidth()/2f,getY()+Gdx.input.getY(pointerUsed)-getHeight()/2f);
        }

        @Override
        public void dragStart(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer) {
            pointerUsed = pointer;  // will be reset to -1 at the end of update() 
            isDragging = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void dragStop(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer) {
            isDragging = false;
        }
    });
mainStage.addActor(playerLight);
```

Both Listener work separetly as i want them to.

The problem is that when I move the object on the stage (playerLight)  with one finger and try to pan up with another finger Gdx seems to not recognize the second input or at least Gdx can´t find an input with another ID.

I tried:

1. To put the object on another stage (in this case the HUD stage)
2. To not  ask for the  ID in the mainStage listener, which lead to triggering both listeners  simulationously when moving my object up (as expected).

Answer (score 0):

Actors will have a default Listener when it's added on `Stage`. What you should do is instead of using `DragListener` use the Listener in your `mainStage` with the method `pan`. Here's how you move your Actor inside your `mainStage`

```
public void pan(InputEvent event, float x, float y, float deltaX, float deltaY) 
 {
    // get a specific actor on the stage
   if (event.getTarget().equals(actor)) 
    {
     float dx = x - actor.getWidth() / 2;
     float dy = y - actor.getHeight() / 2;
      actor.setPosition(dx,dy);
     return;
    }

 }
```

It's that simple. We subtract `actor.getWidth() / 2;` and `actor.getHeight() / 2;` so that when your finger touch the `Actor` it will position on the center of your finger.

Comment: That improved my app by a bit, thanks! Multitouch, however, still doesn´t work. When I move my actor and pan the stage on another spot  with another finger, nothing happens. When releasing my actor, swiping up works again...